# why is the second gerund incorrect?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, gerunds

I want to indicate the following goals by using gerunds. Grammarly indicates that the first gerund (Finding) is ok but the second one "**Sharing**" is incorrect.

My end goals are:

1. **Finding** reliable sources of food to use in the dry season in Nubien and exploring the possible effects on its economy due to climate change.
2. **Sharing** the findings in my thesis with the authorities of Nubien so that they can have accurate information to regulate the use of resources among the economic sectors.

Comment: Neither 1 nor 2 is a complete sentence, which is probably why Grammarly is complaining about 2.  I'm guessing it's not complaining about 1 because either Grammarly is sometimes wrong or because it glued the introductory phrase "My end goals are:" onto phrase 1 and interpreted it as a complete sentence.

Comment: My Grammarly does not indicate an error in either (except for the unknown word "Nubien")

Answer (score 2):

If we treat the sentence as being : "my end goals are (1) finding ..., and (2)...,

then you should not end the first point with a period.

Punctuation is not, strictly speaking, grammar: different style guides set out different rules. Given the length of these phrases, I might arrange it as follows

> My ultimate goals are:

> (1.) Finding ...;

> (2.) Exploring ...; and

> (3.) Sharing ....

Others may have a different set of preferences on how to punctuate lists.